# Using Oracle Function with return value in c# application

Tags: c#, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION xxpos.IS_USER_VALID(
  user_name     IN VARCHAR,
  user_password IN VARCHAR)
RETURN boolean
AS
user_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO user_count
    FROM xxpos.service_users
    WHERE user_id     = user_name
    AND user_password = user_password;
    IF user_count     >0 THEN
        return true;
    ELSE
       return false;
    END IF;
END;
```

I created the oracle function. And i tried to use it in C# my application
Like:

```
        Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter[] parameters = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter[3];
        parameters[0] = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("user_name", this.UserName);
        parameters[1] = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("user_password", this.Password);
        parameters[2] = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("is_valid", 
            Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Object, 
            System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        using (MyOracleClient myOracleClient = new MyOracleClient())
        {
            myOracleClient.MyExicuteNonQuery(Command.IsUserValid, parameters);
            this.userValid = (bool)parameters[2].Value;
        }
```

But It doesn't work out.
Cloud you Please enplane me, the right way of using Parameters with c# Database connection.

Comment: Getting a exception on the parameter "is_valid"
Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: is_valid

Comment: Did you try setting the value of `Size` for the `ReturnValue` param

Answer (score 4):

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#sthref308):

> When binding by position (default) to a function, ODP.NET expects the
>   return value to be bound first, before any other parameters.

Picky, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.userValid = ( (Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleBoolean)  parameters[2].Value).IsTrue;
```